# Using .remove() vs .detach() for removal of to-do list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a to-do list using jQuery ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VXmPrO)). In order to remove list items, I used

```
 $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

I'm wondering whether it would matter if I used .detach() rather than .remove() (having tried both, functionality seems to be the same). I read the documentation and understand that .remove() removes the element itself as well as everything inside it as well as bound events, while .detach() does the same but keeps jQuery data associated with the removed element.

What would be the ramifications, if any, if I used .detach() and thus maintained associated data?

Comment: If you wish to give the user the option to regret that he removed something from the to-do list use detach(). Read doc here: https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove` takes elements out of the `DOM` and everything inside it, while `detach` removes the `DOM` and keeps the data if you want to reinsert it elsewhere :

https://api.jquery.com/detach/

> The `.detach()` method is the same as `.remove()`, except that `.detach()`
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

use `remove()` to delete the element and `detach()` to move it somewhere else.

```
$('#myTodo').remove(); // deletes the todo

const detachedTodo = $('#myTodo').detach(); // removes the todo and keep it in a variable

$('#addButton').on('click', function(){
     ('#completeTodos').append(detachedTodo) ; // add the removed todo to the completed list
});
```

Comment: No need to use `detach()` if you are immediately appending it somewhere else.

Comment: you're right but this is just for the sake of the example :P

Comment: Doesn't seem like a practical example though

Comment: well .. the point is to demonstrate how the function works and this is the simplest thing i can come up with right now.